# What is the return type of a function which returns itself?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, typescript-eslint

```
setInterval(
    (function func() /* :() => ??? */ {
        console.log(`I will be invoked immediately!`);

        return func;
    })(),
    10000
);
```

Greeting, I am new to Typescript.

I used to use `setInterval()` in this way in JS so that I can invoke the callback function of `setInterval()` immediately instead of wait for 10 seconds before first run. However, when I moved to TS now I don't know what to put here as its return type. I tried to use `any` like `() => any`, but seems that it may break the rule of **@typescript-eslint**: `Missing return type on function.eslint(@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type)`.

Anyone can give me some advice? Thanks in advance.

p.s. I know the way that I am using `setInterval()` may not good, but I just want to get rid of this.

Comment: Although I look forward to (hopefully) seeing someone come up with a clever answer, the real answer is to pull the function out into an enclosing scope, call it, *then* set the interval.

Comment: @JaredSmith Haha, this may be a defect of one-liner. Therefore, I said I know this may not good, but I really want to see if there is a way to get rid of it.

Comment: `explicit-function-return-type` in this case is just harmful... Typescript is clever enough to infer the type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would avoid any lint rule that forces explicit types in all situations, or at the very least I would probably disable it for this use case.

If you leave the function as is, Ts will infer the return type correctly.

If you want to spell it out, you can use a recursive type:

```
type Fn = () => Fn;
setInterval(
    (function func() : Fn {
        console.log(`I will be invoked immediately!`);

        return func;
    })(),
    10000
);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can define it exactly as TS defines it: `typeof func`.

```
function func(): typeof func { ... }
```

This is saying explicitly that the function returns a function with its own signature, so it is also expressive.